# Running a query for each entry in a list of tables

Tags: mysql

I intend to write a procedure to run a query on each of the tables in a provided list (can be a comma separated list or a table - undecided on that yet)

I started off with creating a while loop to iterate through each element in the provided list. Have been able to extract each element but I don't know how to run a query for that extracted element/table.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS retain_demo_clients$$
CREATE PROCEDURE retain_demo_clients()
BEGIN

DECLARE counter  INT(10);
DECLARE client_tables  VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE table_count  INT(10);
DECLARE table_in_process  VARCHAR(255);

SET counter = 1;
SET table_count = 3;
SET client_tables = 'client_table, somerandomstuff, somemorestuff';


WHILE (counter < table_count +1) DO
    SET table_in_process = substring_index(substring_index(client_tables, ',',counter),',',-1);
    SELECT table_in_process;
    SET counter = counter +1;
END WHILE;


END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL retain_demo_clients();
```

I expect to do something like 'select * from table_in_process'. Would also appreciate if there is a better way to loop through the list of tables.

Here is DBFiddle link, if someone wants to tinker: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v6EMsiWvXFrBoNLgoZwDVX/1

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: @Strawberry I need to great a sample data and I need some few operations on each table. I thought of writing a procedure and call it for each of the tables in the schema. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I probably don't really understand what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXECUTE` to run a text that represent a single statement

```
SET @someQuery =  CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_in_process ) ;
PREPARE preparable_stmt FROM @someQuery;
EXECUTE preparable_stmt;
```